# Load XML file into ReaderSetting

Tags: c#, xml, filereader

I have 2 XML files.
I want to compare them using XML Reader, for this I have already built a XML Reader method and provided the attributes for the Reader Settings.

Now the reader should run through, compare the two into a hash. If the hash is the same, then try catch to delete the old or the new one.

My problem is:
The reader needs an integer to compare the hashes (this is what I see)
However, I can only convert the XML path into a string and then pass it.

How do I get these files into the reader ?

```
private string xmlOld = @"c:\temp\List-FULL(xsd).xml".ToString();
private string xmlNew = @"c:\temp\List-FULL(xsd)2.xml".ToString();
```

Here is the Method:

```
public bool XmlListReader()
{
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.IgnoreComments = true;
    settings.IgnoreProcessingInstructions = true;
    settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;

    try
    {
        int xmlHashNew = settings.GetHashCode(); // Part to Load 2 XML files, with Readersettings.
        int xmlHashOld = settings.GetHashCode();
        File.Delete(xmlHashAlt.Equals(xmlHashNeu) == false ? xmlOld : xmlNew);

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need an XmlReader not an XmlReaderSetings.

Comment: @jdweng
XmlReader xmlComparer = new XmlReader();
xmlComparer.Value.Equals(...) something like that ?

Comment: XmlReader xmlComparer = XmlReader.Create(filename);

Comment: Show us content of your xml files. Do you want delete whole file or just several nodes from it?